# Using archivesBaseName in a gradle project has no effect

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm trying to name the artifact that gets built by gradle. Look at this `build.gradle`:

```
archivesBaseName='this_is_ignored'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
archivesBaseName='this_is_also_ignored'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.+'
}
```

I also tried in `gradle.properties`:

```
archivesBaseName=`this_is_ignored_too`
```

In every case `./gradlew build` generates a .jar file based on the folder where the project resides (which as I understand it is `project.name`, I was just hoping to override that with `archivesBaseName`).

In other words, I want:

```
~/gradle-helloworld > ./gradlew build
```

to generate `this_is_ignored.jar`, but it's generating `gradle-helloworld.jar` instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you set `archivesBaseName` before applying the plugin, you'll introduce a dynamic property (which gives a deprecation warning). This dynamic property will then shadow the one introduced by the plugin, which is why the second assignment doesn't have the desired effect either. The solution is to only set the property *after* applying the plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Turning [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser)'s comment into a CW answer.)

If you set `archivesBaseName` before applying the plugin, you'll introduce a dynamic property (which gives a deprecation warning). This dynamic property will then shadow the one introduced by the plugin, which is why the second assignment doesn't have the desired effect either. The solution is to only set the property *after* applying the plugin.